# Display an image as a splash screen when running Windows batch file, vbscript/wscript or Python console script

Tags: python, image, vbscript, batch-file, console-application

Any ideas how I can display an image file (bmp or png) centered on the screen as an application splash screen when running a Windows console script based on a batch file, vbscript/wscript or Python console script?

I'm not interested in a wxPython solution - that's too much overhead just to implement a cosmetic feature like a splash screen.

Thank you,
Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

A low-tech, ugly approach? How about opening an image viewer with the bitmap and killing it after some time or when the initializations are done? ;-)

You certainly have no native way of doing this in a batch file. From VBScript you could use an [HTA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_Application). PowerShell has no problems of doing this with Windows Forms but wasn't on your list, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can surely cook it up using the Win32 API and the `win32api` Python module.

How about [this recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/120687-low-resource-win32-splashscreen/)? Alternatively, [this article](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/w-d/dislog/splashscreens/article.php/c5029) has some C code that can be converted for invocation from Python with `win32api`.

Answer (score 0):

Try TK, it is included with python.  Also, PyGtk is lighter than wxPython, but I ended up bitting the bullet and using wxPython for the same purpose recently, it is heavy, but it didn't have any affect on the script performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a late reply to the mix. I think this is an interesting option worth looking at:

http://www.quicksplash.net